# How to set vb textbox to the contents of a "buffer"?

Tags: vb6

I am new to VB. I am testing some old VB code. The code is as follows -

```
  Public GlobalCommArea() As Byte
  ...
  ...
  'GlobalCommArea is set to some value
```

Now, I want to see the contents of this GlobalCommArea variable. (By the way, is it a variable?)

So I tried

```
  outputBox.Text = GlobalCommArea
```

But the outputBox (which is a textbox) didn't show anything. What should I do to print the contents of GlobalCommArea into the textbox?

Comment: What does the buffer contain? If it's ASCII text, Tom's answer will work fine. If anythign else, you'll need to tell us before we can give a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Byte data type is an array of bytes actually. You need to convert it to a string.
Use this to convert it:

```
outputBox.Text = StrConv(GlobalCommArea, vbUnicode)
```

Depending on what's stored in GlobalCommArea you may have to change the vbUnicode parameter.

Hope this helps

Comment: Also remember that null characters will cause the value to be truncated in the TextBox.